# JavaScript cookie issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, settimeout, session-cookies

I have been giving this code to implement on a number of different websites, however there is an issue in google chrome where the toolbar appears and disappears within 300 milliseconds (time set in the index.html). I have checked it in FireFox and Safari and it works but not in Chrome strangely. I am aware that this is a lot of code to go through but any tips would be very welcomed.

full code: http://jsfiddle.net/C4EkZ/

```
    if (cookieBar) {
        cookieBar.init( {

            el: 'div',
            msg: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
            url: 'http://www.google.com',
            linkText: 'Here',
            linkTarget: '_new',
            closeLink: true,
            animateOpen: {                  
                opacity: '1',
                paddingTop: '10px',
                paddingBottom: '10px',
                duration: 800
            },
            animateClosed: {                    
                opacity: '0',
                paddingTop: '0px',
                paddingBottom: '0px',
                duration: 800,
                complete:function() {
                    var c = document.getElementById('cookieBar');
                    document.body.removeChild(c);
                }
            },
            delay: 500,
            hideForSession: true
        }); 
    };
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the expected behaviour and what is the actual behaviour?

Comment: on page load it suppose to appear and then you would click on close to make it go away. I'd say similar to most cookie toolbars...

Comment: Could it be that I am running it locally? I am trying to figure this out but it's really hard for me... I am hoping it's not something small as usual...

Comment: I see it in the fiddle too open/close, open/close

Comment: Why `setTimeout( (function() { ... }),options.delay || 0)` and not `setTimeout(function() { ... },options.delay || 0)`

Comment: Hi there, as mentioned earlier this code was given to me, so I am myself going through it trying to understand it...

Comment: @mplungjan edited the script following your changes, still same issue....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27966/discussion-between-alex-and-mplungjan)

Comment: Sorry I'm off for today